# Conceptually, what is a pullback doing in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm struggling to understand what a pullback does conceptually. For context, here is the setup I was given:

Let $(M,g_M)$ and $(N,g_N)$ be Riemannian manifolds and let $p \in M$. We say $M$ and $N$ are isometric if there exists $F: M \to N$, a diffeomorphism, such that $F^*g_N=g_M$. We call $F^*$ the pullback by F. The effect of the pullback on $g_N$ can be expressed as $$F^* g_N(v,w)=g_N(DF_p(v),DF_p(w)),$$
where $v,w \in T_pM$.

So what is $F^*$ and what is it really doing? In this case, it seems to be employing the map  $DF_p$ to make a new map, $F^*g_N: T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ that allows us to use the $g_N$ metric within $T_pM$ (using the intermediate step of passing through $T_{F(p)}N$). Is this a  decent conceptual description of what it's doing, and is this what a pullback does in general?

If this is what's happening, what is the difference between something like the transpose of the differential of $F$ at $p$ and a pullback of $F$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's what it is. $1$-forms are dual to tangent vectors, and pulling back $1$-forms is the adjoint of pushing forward tangent vectors by the differential of the map. The action on higher-order tensors (or differential forms) is algebraically induced from this.